# How to verify if the right activity is open using Assertion appium

Tags: android, appium, ui-automation, assertion

1. How to verify if the android app is launched correctly when click app icon(pass or fail)?
2. How to verify if splash screen is display after app is launched?
3. How to verify if the right activity is open(pass or fail)?

Answer (score 0):

1. You should not test this "feature" specifically, since Android System takes care of this. You should start from test 2.
2. Find an element you are sure is present in the splash screen and validate it with `isDisplayed()`
3. Same as previous

Answer (score 0):

To verify current activity, try(Python):

```
   self.driver.start_activity("your_app_package_here", "your_app_activity")
   activity_name = self.driver.current_activity
   assert activity_name == "your_app_activity"
```